# CakePHP Updating status Twitter and Facebook

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, cakephp, twitter

I was wondering how I can make a full Twitter and Facebook status updater in CakePHP. 
Does anyone ideas to make this or examples.

I read the API reference but I can't find where I should start. 

I hope you will have an example.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For Twitter see:

See: http://hiteshanjara.com/cakephp/update-twitter-status-in-cakephp/
and: http://www.web7.co/update-twitter-status-remotely-cakephp-component/

And here's a link for Facebook:
http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more